# mturk API gives "specified claims are invalid" message about half the time; resubmitting randomly fixes

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, hash, mechanicalturk

I'm using a custom PHP script to submit requests to the mturk API, based on the signature functions from [the PHP-AWS library](https://code.google.com/p/php-aws/source/browse/trunk/class.turk.php?spec=svn26&r=26). Here's an example of a request:

`https://mechanicalturk.amazonaws.com/?Service=AWSMechanicalTurkRequester&AWSAccessKeyId=MYKEY&Version=2012-03-25&Operation=NotifyWorkers&Signature=j+4UTX9x3EKltvWpoxIkp4BM6S4=&Timestamp=2015-06-25T09:37:51Z&Subject=test&MessageText=just+testing+&WorkerId.1=SOMEID`

Sometimes a given script will work, and at other times the same script will return an error like this:

`AWS.BadClaimsSupplied The specified claims are invalid.   Based on your request, your signature should be generated using the following string: AWSMechanicalTurkRequesterNotifyWorkers2015-06-25T09:37:51Z.  Check to make sure your system clock and timezone is not incorrect.  Our current system time: 2015-06-25T09:37:51Z.  (1435225071849)`

When I get the `AWS.BadClaimsSupplied` error, repeatedly rerunning the script will cause it to eventually work. By "work," I mean that either API returns `true` and the desired action is taken, or it returns an error that's relevant to the action I'm requesting.

I assume that if I were performing the hash incorrectly or with the wrong signature, then it would never work*. The intermittent nature of the problem makes me think it's a timing error. But the example above shows an error message in which the time I used for my signature is the same as their time, so that doesn't seem like the problem either.

*okay, it would work once in every 2^160 tries.

I tried backdating my timestamps by 1 second just in case I was a little ahead of them; that didn't change the results. I can't think of any other way to debug this.

Comment: You'll have intermittent success substantially more than 1/2^160 of the time if you are failing to urlescape/urlencode your signature, or encoding it "mostly" correctly... particularly the way you handle any `+` appearing in it.  Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/a/17825022/1695906

Comment: Ohhhhhhhhh, now I understand. Thank you! Do you want to write this up as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message makes it sound like the problem is with the string being hashed, but the actual problem is that some hashed strings include special characters. The characters `+`, `/`, and `=` affect how the URL is parsed and will interfere with reading your signature. Rerunning the request with a different time string will randomly return a hash without those characters, allowing the request to work.

Solution: Simply run `urlencode()` on the signature before making the API call. If for some reason you don't want to do that, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17825022/1146835) provides some code that encodes those specific characters only, but I think the standard function is more comprehensive and safer.